# Where can I learn more about this approach to defining mathematical structures?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Usually, a mathematical structure is defined as a tuple. e.g. A poset is a pair $(X,\leq).$ But there is another, arguably more natural approach to defining mathematical structures, which I'm about to describe.

**Question. Is there somewhere I can learn more about this approach?**

---

We're going to define the class of all posets. But, this is just an example - this question is not specifically about posets.

Let $\Sigma$ denote the class of all sets. Then we assert the existence of a class $\Pi$ of all posets equipped with the following data.

A function $U : \Pi \rightarrow \Sigma$ that takes a poset to its underlying set.

A function $R : \Pi \rightarrow \Sigma$ that takes a poset to its non-strict order relation. We require that for all posets $\pi$ it holds that $R(\pi) \subseteq [U(\pi)]^2.$

If we want this data to completely determine a poset up to equality, we can do the following. Write $(U,R)$ for the mapping $\pi \mapsto (U(\pi),R(\pi)).$ Then we can furthermore assume that $(U,R)$ is injective.

Finally, we need some axioms. To this end, lets assert that for all $u,r \in \Sigma$ such that $r \subseteq u^2,$ the following are equivalent.

- There exists $\pi \in \Pi$ such that $U(\pi)=u$ and $R(\pi)=r.$
- The non-strict axioms of a poset hold. Namely

  1. For all $x \in u$ it holds that $(x,x) \in r$.
  2. For all $x,y,z \in u$ it holds that if $(x,y) \in r$ and $(y,z) \in r$ then $(x,z) \in r$.
  3. For all $x,y \in u$ it holds that if $(x,y) \in r$ and $(y,x) \in r$, then $x=y$.

So that's our definition of $\Pi.$ I like this approach because it allows us to define new relations on $\Pi$ in a rather natural way. For instance, if we want to define the strict order on a poset, we can proceed as follows.

**Definition 1.** Assert that $R' : \Pi \rightarrow \Sigma$ is the unique function such that for all $\pi \in \Pi$, letting $u=U(\pi)$ and $r=R(\pi)$ and $r'=R'(\pi)$, we have that $$\forall x,y \in u : (x,y) \in r' \Leftrightarrow (x,y) \in r \wedge x \neq y.$$

So now we have three functions $\Pi \rightarrow \Sigma$, namely $U$, $R$ and $R'$. Now intuitively, a poset is uniquely determined by its underlying set and non-strict order relation, and also by its underlying set and strict order relation. More formally, we say that $(U,R)$ is injective, and so too is $(U,R').$

So yeah. I'm not really advocating this approach, but I just want to learn more. Not really sure which tags to put.

Comment: I don't understand how this gains you anything. When you define posets in terms of tuples, you automatically get these functions $U$ and $R$. Here it seems you also need to prove some uniqueness property of $\Pi$ which seems nontrivial to state to me.

Comment: There *is* a difference between thinking of posets in terms of strict order relations and in terms of non-strict order relations. The difference is that the natural choice of morphisms in the two categories (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) is different: in one category a morphism is something that preserves the non-strict relation and in another a morphism is something that preserves the strict order relation. The latter is too restrictive in practice; most natural morphisms of posets that occur in practice preserve the non-strict relation but not the strict one.

Comment: On the other hand, this style of definition resembles definition via universal property (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property), which you might be interested in learning about. But I don't think this particular example is a good one.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, you make some good points. Let me reply to your first two comments.

Comment: **Reply To Comment 1.** You make a good point. Here's my take on the issue. Consider that one author might define that the **non-strict** order associated with a poset $(u,r)$ is $r$. Whereas another author might define that the **strict** order associated with a poset $(u,r')$ is $r'$. So one author's definition of the function $R$ is precisely the other authors definition of the function $R'$! Clearly, these kinds of details are irrelevant baggage that we're better off without. So I'd like an approach to defining mathematical structures that simply circumvents such issues altogether.

Comment: **Reply To Comment 1 (Cont).** More generally, I think that, in the structures-as-tuples approach, the emphasis is all wrong. For instance, it suggests that we ask ourselves 'what *is* a poset?' A better question would be: 'What data uniquely determines a poset?'. In general, I'd like to see definitions that encourage good questions. Of course, all this noise I'm making doesn't change the fact that, at a technical level, the structures-as-tuples approach suffices.

Comment: **Reply To Comment 2.** I can't say I agree with this point. For any given class of structures, there will be multiple ways of making that class into a category. And perhaps more than one of these ways is fruitful and interesting (think: metric spaces). So don't choose your morphisms right at the outset! We're better off defining our structures first, and then afterwards using those structures to define one or more categories. At least, that is how I view mathematics. Of course, it goes without saying that everyone is free to view things differently.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Category Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory).

I don't claim to understand it well, and I find it hard to determine what, exactly, you're asking, but I think you're looking for a way to characterize the structure of mathematical objects in some ontological way.

It's said that one shouldn't learn category theory until one already knows category theory. Basically, to work in this context you kind of already need to know the proofs of the more specialized cases. But once you understand the relations, it becomes a very powerful generalization of some quite closely-related concepts.

At least... that's how I understand it all.

Comment: Congratulations for your first gold badge. $~~\Large\color{gold}{\maltese}$